# How to append key and values to a dataframe without creating each time row of column name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe, dictionary

So I am trying to apped values and key from a dict to a dataframe, I for that when looping in the dict I create columns with the name, so far it works but there is a problem. Each time I loop in the dict I get, new row of column name I would like to avoid. How can I do that:

Input data in the dictionnary

```
{'all': ['463\tQuels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous revenons à la fiche de fonction, elle résout ce problème de technologie, avec une grande facilité.\tM',
 '2647\tCela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous devons mettre à jour tous les Magelis que nous avons............\tC',
 "5391\tJe ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité du produit, donc cela ne changera rien pour moi. Je continuerai à l'acheter.\tM",
 "1120\tSur les stations de pompage, c'est très intéressant car environnement pollué, corrosif ?\tM"],
 "am": ['463\tQuels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous revenons à la fiche de fonction, elle résout ce problème de technologie, avec une grande facilité.\tM',
 '2647\tCela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous devons mettre à jour tous les Magelis que nous avons............\tC',
 "5391\tJe ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité du produit, donc cela ne changera rien pour moi. Je continuerai à l'acheter.\tM",
 "1120\tSur les stations de pompage, c'est très intéressant car environnement pollué, corrosif ?\tM"]}
```

```
for k, v in Liste_phrases_retraduit.items():
    v.pop(0)
    v = [i.split("\t") for i in v]
    df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns = ['identifiant', 'verbatim', 'etiquette'] )
    df['id_langue'] = k
    print(df.head())
```

Result

```
  identifiant                                           verbatim etiquette  \
0         463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...         M   
1        2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...         C   
2        5391  Cela ne changera pas la qualité du produit, je...         M   
3        1120  C'est très intéressant, parce que c'est un env...         M   
4        4021  C'est bien pensé. La couleur, la présentation ...         M   

  id_langue  
0       aBr  
1       aBr  
2       aBr  
3       aBr  
4       aBr  
  identifiant                                           verbatim etiquette  \
0         463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...         M   
1        2647  Cela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous ...         C   
2        5391  Je ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité d...         M   
3        1120  Sur les stations de pompage, c'est très intére...         M   
4        4021  C'est bien pensé. La représentation colorée et...         M   

  id_langue  
0       all  
1       all  
2       all  
3       all  
4       all
```

expectation

```
  identifiant                                           verbatim etiquette  \
0         463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...         M   
1        2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...         C   
2        5391  Cela ne changera pas la qualité du produit, je...         M   
3        1120  C'est très intéressant, parce que c'est un env...         M   
4        4021  C'est bien pensé. La couleur, la présentation ...         M   

  id_langue  
0       aBr  
1       aBr  
2       aBr  
3       aBr  
4       aBr  

0         463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...         M   
1        2647  Cela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous ...         C   
2        5391  Je ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité d...         M   
3        1120  Sur les stations de pompage, c'est très intére...         M   
4        4021  C'est bien pensé. La représentation colorée et...         M   
 
0       all  
1       all  
2       all  
3       all  
4       all

0         463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...         M   
1        2647  Cela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous ...         C   
2        5391  Je ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité d...         M   
3        1120  Sur les stations de pompage, c'est très intére...         M   
4        4021  C'est bien pensé. La représentation colorée et...         M   
 
0       german  
1       german  
2       german 
3       german 
4       german
```

How do I get rid of that line. I could save data like this and then filter and suppress it in excel file but since I have to send the code , it would not be really professional.

Comment: please provide reproducible inputs for your problem

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I added the input

Comment: Could you double-check the input you have added? Seems to throw some errors when trying to store it in a variable. Seems like you are missing a few quotes/commas or both

Comment: You are creating a new dataframe, and printing its `head()` (i.e. the first 5 lines) at each iteration, so you will always get the headers. You may want to concatenate the dataframes and just output the final result?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I changed the data